# Notification showing only once and never showing again thereafter

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am having a scheduled FirebaseJob, once it is completed, it schedules itself again, with next window, ON_ANY_NETWORK. It is doing its job great and as expected. From which i am calling a service which creates a new notification every time with pending intent. like :

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", "NotificationMessage");
    //resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("My App name")
            .setContentText("Content text")
            .setTicker("This is a ticker text")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("This is a long text"))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));

    if (notificationManager != null)
    {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }
```

**Which is showing the notification for first time only**, as i am expecting. I do not want any user to swipe it until, the app is opened again. And once app is opened from this notification, i am cancelling the notification like :

```
int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= 234;
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

**But when again my job starts executing and executes the same code shown above for creating notification, it executes the code, but the notification is not getting displayed again.** Any help will be appreciated from board members. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `MY_NOTIFICATION_ID` is always same. Instead, for example, you can set `MY_NOTIFICATION_ID` to be equal to `System.currentTimeMillis()`:

```
int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID= System.currentTimeMillis();
String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
mNotificationManager.cancel(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Comment: I was missing stopSelf(); in onStartCommand() method, so next time onCreate() method was not getting called, and in the same method i was creating the notification, thats why it was showing notification on first time only. By the way its nice to see your help